# C# - Access SQLite database for WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, connection-string

I have create Set up file for WPF application and the database is SQLite DB. After the installation the SQLite DB is located this path in C folder,

C:\Program Files (x86)\myCompany\myScanApp.

[image]

Then I have written connection string like this way for establishing a connection to SQLite DB,

```
static SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Program Files (x86)\myCompany\myScanApp\test.s3db;");
```

Then I have created a Setup file again and then run this application on another PC. But, it is failing to run in the PC. How can I access DB in application?

Comment: What does “failing to run” mean? It's throwing an exception? You need to [tell us the exception](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Also, `C:\Program Files (x86)\` is typically not a place the user can or wants to change; if you expect users to change your database you should copy it to a place the user can change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using(SQLiteConnection conn= new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Program Files (x86)\myCompany\myScanApp\test.s3db;"))
{
    conn.Open();

    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("Select * from yourTable", conn);
    SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
       Console.WriteLine(reader["YourColumn"]);

 
    reader.Close();
}
```

Something like this should work. Here whole article [**Getting started with SQLite in C#**](https://web.archive.org/web/20190820042446/http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/)

Comment: Hi I have also written this connection sting, but it caused error when I am trying to run applications after installation. How can I ?

Comment: @AbhilashJA Causing error doesn't mean anything to me. https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/ here article about connection strings. Don't use static connection string also ! The whole code here is part of a Method.

Comment: Yes. Right... it's working. I did write connection string like this:-

 public SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Program Files (x86)\hedronix\qScan\test.s3db;");

Thanks.

Comment: @AbhilashJA okay if it is working make the answer correct